# Is there a way to globally change a css variable?

Tags: html, css, css-variables

So I've got css to change `--size` to 500px, and a `:root` that sets it 0 zero. When I change `--size` on hover, it changes locally, and doesn't change the width of another element.

My HTML is:

```html
<html>
<head>...</head>
<body>
<nav>...</nav>
<main>
<a href="new.html" class="btnLink">Create a new project!</a>
<div class="underline"></div>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Where "..." is stuff I'm too lazy to put (and know that its not going to add anything to the question)

My CSS:

```css
.btnLink:hover {
    --size: 500px;
}

.btnLink {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    --movefar: translate(-50%,0);
    transform: var(--movefar);
}

.underline {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(6rem + 1px); /* Somehow magically puts it the place I want */
    left: 50%;
    transform: var(--movefar); /* doesn't work for some reason */
    overflow: clip;
    background-color: white;
    color: transparent;
    height: 1px;
    width: var(--size);
}
```

In this case I am using 2 variables to control it, but they update locally, so it doesn't work. Also, I realize theres a way to do this with javascript, but I would rather not use javascript with this.

Comment: `.btnLink:hover + .underline {
    --size: 500px;
}`

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74816531/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a way, you can use the plus (+) in CSS, for example:

```
.btnLink:hover + .anything {
--size:500px;
}
.btnLink:hover + div {
--size:500px;
}
.btnLink:hover + span:last-of-type {
--size:500px;
}
```

or in your case:

```
.btnLink:hover + .underline {
--size:500px;
}
```

Comment: It works, but only for --size, and when I use --movefar as well, it doesn't goto the same position as .btnLink